# Ethernet cables dying quickly

Tags: ethernet, cable

We have to regular replace ethernet cables. A few have said its because we are close to the ocean. We about about 2 miles form the ocean. Is this true and if so can we do anything about it.

Comment: How often are the cables moved?

Comment: Sounds like you have cheap cables. How would the ocean effect this?
Also, what is the time length between install and replacement. 1 day? 1 year?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to suspect power issues with one or more of your devices.

Comment: What does a cable you need to replace look like? Are the plugged in/out often? What are the symptoms, are there transmit errors?

Comment: I live on an island, the building I work is 75 feet away from the Pacific Ocean.  I have never seen cables degrade because I am near the Ocean.

Answer (score 0):

One possiiblity as to what they might mean by "too close to the ocean" is that you have high humidity in your work environment which can cause corrosion on the ethernet head contacts.

If this is the case then you can take a cotton swap or a Q-tip and wet the tip with some alcohol. Rub the contacts on the ends of the ethernet cable and allow it to dry for a minute or two. Make sure it is dry before you plug it back in.

If this isn't the case then I can only think of two other possibilities:

1. You may have a short circuit near your ethernet input, make sure no part of your motherboard back plate is touching inside your ethernet port.
2. Your power may be fluctuating due to brown outs or other similar events causing a surge through the cable. If its a mission critical machine you should put it on a battery backup to compensate for such events.